# How to pass an array to a sql stored procedure from java program

Tags: java, sql

I have to send an array to a stored procedure as a parameter from java program. how can we do that. please help me in this

Comment: What database? Arrays and stored procedures are a tricky topic when it comes to handling them with JDBC. Also, are you just using plain JDBC, or some sort of abstraction, such as JPA?

Comment: Which data base do you use. For PL/SQL I think you can find an answer here http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:2920034229577885::::P11_QUESTION_ID:712625135727

Comment: And please add the signature of the stored procedure as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a vendor centric implementation and so would be different for different databases.
For Oracle you need to use ArrayDescriptor class of oracle.sql package.
Follow the link below for a sutable answer discussed on AskTom site: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:2906896739396193::::P11_QUESTION_ID:712625135727

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your database. Some databases (for example Postgres, HSQLDB) and their JDBC drivers support anonymous arrays, which you can set with

```
Object[] array = // ...
pstmt.setObject(index, array);
```

Oracle is more complex as it needs a typed object.